# How to fetch word from string on terminal only in linux

Tags: linux, string, shell

I have string "org.acumos.onboarding:onboarding-app-open:jar:3.7.9-app", from the string, I want to fetch 3.7.9-app, on to the linux terminal only through some shell commands, not through some file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
[user@hostname~]$ echo "org.acumos.onboarding:onboarding-app-open:jar:3.7.9-app" | cut -f4 -d :
3.7.9-app
```

-d flag represents delimiter. -f flag represents which field you want to grab.

Comment: Thanks man, I was struggling with awk command, but I guess cut command would be better to use

Comment: @SvDhote The awk is `awk '{print $4}' FS=:` or `awk -v FS=: '{print $4}'`

Comment: @SvDhote You can also use awk. 
echo "org.acumos.onboarding:onboarding-app-open:jar:3.7.9-app" | awk -F [:] '{print $4}'

Comment: @William can you please share, how to pass the string in the above awk

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is a bit more flexible than `cut`; you can specify the last component rather than the 4th:

```
echo 'org.acumos.onboarding:onboarding-app-open:jar:3.7.9-app' \
| awk '{print $NF}' FS=:
```